# Why can't call the dictionary's value with its key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

We can call value in a dictionary with its key.

```
class mymodel(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class mytest(object,metaclass=mymodel):
    pass
```

Check its attribution.

```
mytest._instances
{}
```

Call `mytest` first time to let it contain an attribution `_instances`.

```
mytest()
<__main__.mytest object at 0x7f3286774b20>
mytest._instances
{<class '__main__.mytest'>: <__main__.mytest object at 0x7f3286774b20>}
type(mytest._instances)
<class 'dict'>
mytest._instances.keys()
dict_keys([<class '__main__.mytest'>])
```

Call its value with key:

```
mytest._instances[<class '__main__.mytest'>]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    mytest._instances[<class '__main__.mytest'>]
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
mytest._instances["<class '__main__.mytest'>"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "<class '__main__.mytest'>"
```

Try to escape with backslash `\`:

```
mytest._instances[\<class '__main__.mytest'\>]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
mytest._instances["\<class '__main__.mytest'\>"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "\\<class '__main__.mytest'\\>"
```

How can call the value in  `mytest._instances`  with key then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at mytest._instances, it is showing you what the dictionary contains:

```
mytest._instances
    {<class '__main__.mytest'>: <__main__.mytest object at 0x7f3286774b20>}
```

i.e. the dictionary key is mytest's class and the dictionary value is a specific instance of my test

So you can get the value by using:

```
mytest._instances[mytest]
    <__main__.mytest object at 0x7f3286774b20>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a string, it's an class object.

You should use:

```
mytest._instances[mytest]
```